# Let G be a finite group with more than one element. Show that G has an element of prime order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite group with more than one element. Show that $G$ has an element of prime order

Comment: Does Z4 (the mod 4 group) have an element of prime order? The identity has order 1, and the other elements have order 4.

Comment: @barrycarter No, $2$ has order $2$.

Comment: I can't believe I made such a simple error.

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** Let $a \neq 1$ be an element of $G$ of order $k$ and $d \in \mathbb{N}$ be a number such that $d \mid k$. What is the order of $a^d$?

Comment: +1 You really show the OP how to find that element in $G$. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Let $|G|=n$ and $p\mid n$ such that $p$ be a prime , so it is enough to apply Cauchy's Theorem and find that desired element.

Comment: Nice observation! +1

Comment: @amWhy: Thanks for your kindness.

Comment: Cauchy's overkill.